# Se puede comparar strings por contenido aunque no esté en el mismo orden?? c#

Tags: c#

existe algún método que compare los strings por contenido aunque no estén en el mismo orden? Por ejemplo si yo tengo esto

```
String s1="3,4";
String s2="4,3";
```

A la hora comparar ambos de true en vez de false como es normalmente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando `Linq`, la implementación de lo que deseas se hace muy sencilla:

```
public static bool Compare(string s1,string s2)
    {
       return s1.Length == s2.Length 
              && String.Concat(s1.OrderBy(c => c)) == String.Concat(s2.OrderBy(c => c));
    }
```

La idea se puede resumir en dos pasos:

1. Si la longitud de los strings no es igual devuelve `False`.
2. Si la longitud de los strings es igual, y los strings ordenados coinciden, entonces, los strings son iguales.

Te dejo un ejemplo en [.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/q0dzZN) donde puedes testearlo.